# Rails Environments Best Practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2

I've been mainly developing rails locally (in development environment), and will need to make the site live soon on nginx, ec2. I know that rails has three environments that come with the project. I have few open-ended questions about switching environments that will help me accelerate the process.

1. How necessary is it to run in the "production" environment in ec2? In other words, what are the cons of simply running the same "development" environment that I've been running to develop?
2. I skimmed through the "Configuring Rails Application"  tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) but it mostly sounds like jibberish to me. From your experiences, what are major changes that need to be made (or highly encouraged) in the config files when going from development to production?
3. Anything else that you'd recommend regarding environments?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How necessary is it to run in the "production" environment in ec2? In other words, what are the cons of simply running the same "development" environment that I've been running to develop?

The development environment is designed to expose a lot of internal information that may help you to debug the application. You don't want to expose them to an user, especially in case of exception.

The risk is to expose internal, private, data such as connection strings.

Moreover, the development environment is designed to reload the classes on every request, effectively slowing down a lot the flow of a request. Same applies to the asset pipeline, which is designed to be recompiled at runtime.

Last but not least, gems and libraries rely on the fact that development is not required to be "safe". You don't really want to break this assumption.

> I skimmed through the "Configuring Rails Application" tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) but it mostly sounds like jibberish to me. From your experiences, what are major changes that need to be made (or highly encouraged) in the config files when going from development to production?

Starts with the defaults. They are fine for most of cases. You'll tweak them over the time.

> Anything else that you'd recommend regarding environments?

If you want to use Rails, follow the Rails conventions. ;)

Comment: I understand why running in different environments make sense, I even understand the need for a dev machine and a prod machine, the thing I'm still struggling with is the need to label them as different databases. What's wrong with just pointing the app to a DB on "localhost"? that way when I run the code on my dev machine it will load the local DB (which is dev) and when I push the code to my prod machine it will load the local db (which is prod). Why specify a dev and prod DB on the same machine if you have prod and dev machines? I'm sure there's a good reason I'm not aware of

Comment: Because the db doesn't always run on localhost.